# Web.Config IIS Rewrite Rules

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I have a site which redirects all requests to index.php. However I need a slight change to my web.config.

This is what it currently is in the redirect section:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Process" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

However, I need it so that if someone goes to /news then it will go to `news.php` instead of `index.php`.

What rule would I use and where would I place it? I come from an Apache background but my client is using IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert another rule above the existing on with a few changes to redirect to your location.

This can be done in the IIS manager as well. Doing it through this will allow you to test the syntax you use to see if it works with the urls you want.

```
<rule name="Rewrite-News" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="news" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="news.php" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

So it would all look a bit like this:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite-News" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="news" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="news.php" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Process" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```